# Скрытие ячеек в таблице

Tags: html, css

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    .visib {
      visibility: collapse;
    }
    .visib1 {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table class="definition-table" border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="def-table-pict">Картинка</th>
        <th class="def-table-code">Код</th>
        <th class="def-table-manufacturer">Производитель</th>
        <th class="def-table-title">Название</th>
        <th class="def-table-price">Цена, руб.</th>
        <th class="def-table-price-kl">Цена, баллов</th>
        <th class="def-table-buy">В корзину</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="def-table-pict" rowspan="2">
          <img src="" alt="КОМПРЕССОР АВТОМОБИЛЬНЫЙ" title="КОМПРЕССОР АВТОМОБИЛЬНЫЙ" border="0" height="" width="">
        </td>
        <td class="def-table-code" rowspan="2">PM6508</td>
        <td class="def-table-manufacturer" rowspan="2">ZP</td>
        <td class="def-table-title" rowspan="2">КОМПРЕССОР АВТОМОБИЛЬНЫЙ</td>
        <td class="def-table-price visib">252.58</td>
        <td class="def-table-price-kl visib">253</td>
        <td class="def-table-buy visib">ljjljljj</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="def-table-price ">3 799.65</td>
        <td class="def-table-price-kl ">3800</td>
        <td class="def-table-buy ">kkk</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="def-table-pict" rowspan="2">
          <img src="" alt="Набор инструмента, 14 предметов" title="Набор инструмента, 14 предметов" border="0" height="" width="">
        </td>
        <td class="def-table-code" rowspan="2">PM5120</td>
        <td class="def-table-manufacturer" rowspan="2">ZP</td>
        <td class="def-table-title" rowspan="2">Набор инструмента, 14 предметов</td>
        <td class="def-table-price visib">252.58</td>
        <td class="def-table-price-kl visib ">253</td>
        <td class="def-table-buy visib">ljjljljj</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="def-table-price ">252.58</td>
        <td class="def-table-price-kl ">253</td>
        <td class="def-table-buy ">ljjljljj</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="def-table-pict" rowspan="2">
          <img src="/upload/iblock/991/9917d3130bfe5673542ef54397ef6895.png" alt="ааАаБаОб баГаЛаОаВбб аКаЛббаЕаЙ баЕббаИаГбаАаНаНбб 8 аПбаЕаДаМаЕбаОаВ: 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 аМаМ ZIPOWER 8 pc HEX KEY SET -" title="ааАаБаОб баГаЛаОаВбб аКаЛббаЕаЙ баЕббаИаГбаАаНаНбб 8 аПбаЕаДаМаЕбаОаВ: 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 аМаМ ZIPOWER 8 pc HEX KEY SET -"
          border="0" height="173" width="150">
        </td>
        <td class="def-table-code" rowspan="2">
          PM4161</td>
        <td class="def-table-manufacturer" rowspan="2">
          ZP</td>
        <td class="def-table-title" rowspan="2">ааАаБаОб баГаЛаОаВбб аКаЛббаЕаЙ баЕббаИаГбаАаНаНбб 8 аПбаЕаДаМаЕбаОаВ: 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 аМаМ ZIPOWER 8 pc HEX KEY SET -</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="def-table-price ">
          79.57</td>
        <td class="def-table-price-kl ">80</td>
        <td class="def-table-buy">
          <form action="/shares/bonuses/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="add_form_to_basket">
            <div class="count clearfix">
              <div class="counter">
                <input class="counter_input" size="3" onblur="if (this.value > 5) this.value=5" name="quantity" value="1" id="quantity1766440" type="text">
              </div>
              <div class="counter">
                <div class="quantity_control">
                  <a class="PlusList plus" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="if (BX('quantity1766440').value < 5) BX('quantity1766440').value++;"></a>
                  <a class="MinusList minus" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="if (BX('quantity1766440').value > 1) BX('quantity1766440').value--;"></a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="counter">
                <input class="btn btn-small" onclick="if (5 > 0){yaCounter12899284.reachGoal('CART'); return true;}else{this.disabled=true; return true;}" name="actionADD2BASKET" value="" title="ааОаБаАаВаИбб аВ аКаОбаЗаИаНб" id="link2card1766440" type="submit">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="some-class">
            </div>
            <input name="action" value="BUY" type="hidden">
            <input name="id" value="1766440" type="hidden">
            <input name="actionBUY" value="абаПаИбб" style="display:none;" type="submit">
          </form>
        </td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

мне некоторые `td class="visib"` не нужно отображать. Вопрос как?

Comment: смотря какие эти "некоторые". чтобы не отображать блок, надо ему присвоить `display: none`, например. выберите те, которые надо скрыть, и присвойте

Comment: или, если хотите, чтоб блок продолжал участвовать в разметке страницы, те занимать место, `visibility: hidden`

Answer (score 2):

если вам надо все `td class="visib"` просто спрятать, то вот так:

```
.visib {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: нет, в лисичке не работает

Comment: должно работать. видимо, у вас ошибка в коде. на примере кода из задания - там, где у вас `visibility: collapse;`, пропишите `hidden`. можете прочитать о правилах применения [вот тут](http://htmlbook.ru/css/visibility)

Comment: Нет не работает лисичка 49.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой вариант - установить `display: none;`

```
.visib {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: нет не получается. пробовала. Таблица получается поломанная

Comment: в лисичке не работает